# Why bind item is not updated after control value is changed?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I'm having a hard time binding properties. I'm probably missing something here. The thing is that my object properties are not updated by the interface control changes until I do another interaction with the UI, like press an empty dummy button. This is really odd. What I'm missing here? How can I make the bind property to be updated on control checked change?

Sample:

- Create an empty Form, add a CheckBox and a button.
- Bind the Checkbox to the IsOnSale Car property.
- Add a console writeline to see when IsOnSale  property will be changed.
- Build and click on the Checkbox, IsOnSale wont change (no console msg) until a click on another button or something.
- Click on the dummy button, the IsOnSale property will be changed! What!??

  ```
  private Car car;

  public Form1()
  {
      InitializeComponent();

      car = new Car();
      car.IsOnSale = false;

      checkBox1.DataBindings.Add("Checked", car, "IsOnSale");
  }

  //U dont need this for the test..
  private void btnPrintStatus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      string s = car.ToString();
      Console.WriteLine(s);
  }
  ```

Car is just a class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged. Also, It prints on console every time a property change request is made (just for debugging). As you can see if you build the sample, the change request is only made after a click on the dummy button...

```
internal class Car : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
{
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            string propName = GetName(new { Name });
            UpdateField(ref name, value, propName, null);
        }
    }
    private bool isOnSale;

    public bool IsOnSale
    {
        get { return isOnSale; }
        set
        {
            string propName = GetName(new { IsOnSale });
            UpdateField(ref isOnSale, value, propName, null);
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Car Name: {0}. IsOnSale: {1}", Name, IsOnSale);
    }

    #region  INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
    public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public static string GetName<T>(T item) where T : class
    {
        return typeof(T).GetProperties()[0].Name;
    }

    protected bool UpdateField<T>(ref T field, T newValue, string propertyName, Action action = null)
    {
        bool needChange = !EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, newValue);
        Console.WriteLine("Try to UpdateField {0}. Need update? {1}", propertyName, needChange);

        if (needChange)
        {
            OnPropertyChanging(propertyName);
            field = newValue;
            if (action != null)
                action();
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }
        return needChange;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanging(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangingEventHandler handler = PropertyChanging;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangingEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

**EDIT - workaround**

I have been able to find a work around, but it smells..
I'm using a BackgroundWorker to "get out" of the change event and after that I perform a click on a dummy button.

```
    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Wont work, need to get out of this event.
        //btnDummy.PerformClick();

        //Using another thread to get out of this event:
        RunAsyncBindFixer();
    }

    private void RunAsyncBindFixer()
    {
        var workerBindFixer = new BackgroundWorker();
        workerBindFixer.DoWork += WorkerBindFixer_DoWork;
        workerBindFixer.RunWorkerCompleted += WorkerBindFixer_RunWorkerCompleted;
        Console.WriteLine("Starting RunAsyncBindFixer");
        workerBindFixer.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void WorkerBindFixer_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //Aparently we need nothing here.
        //Thread.Sleep(0);
    }

    void WorkerBindFixer_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("RunAsyncBindFixer RunWorkerCompleted");
        btnDummy.PerformClick();
        //Checked change on a dummy checkbox wont work also
        //ckbDummy.Checked = !ckbDummy.Checked;
        Console.WriteLine("Dummy action applied");
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Databinding defaults to writing the value whenever the bound control is validated, which happens normally when the control loses focus (such as when a button is pressed as in your example)

You can force the databinding to use the onpropertychanged of the control provided the control supports it (in this case `CheckedChanged` , which is supported by the checkbox control)

```
checkBox1.DataBindings.Add("Checked", car, "IsOnSale", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

Comment: Oh! Thanks, that works. I wounder why this is not the default behavior.

Comment: You're very welcome. One of the main reasons of not being the default behaviour would be that the value is only written once the user is finished with the control. For most data binding it's adequate and it prevents rewriting the value multiple times. Especially for bindings on controls such as textboxes. `TextChanged` would be called after each keypress.

Comment: As a complete sidenote, in the work around, while using the default onvalidated binding, you could also have forced a write of the value by using something like `checkBox1.DataBindings[0].WriteValue();` inside the CheckedChanged event.

Comment: Ok, it makes sense for textboxes. Thank you very much for the clarification and the other workaround!